# Field Service Booking an Appointment Error

Tags: permissions, error-messages, field-service-lightning, bookappointment

I am having problem booking an appointment using Salesforce FSL managed package in a sandbox environment. I login as user with the agent permission set and license assigned and I tried booking an appointment using Book Appointment global action in the feed tab. After selecting recommended schedule, I am greeted with this error:

```
Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 03r1m000000UCh1AAG; first error: INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_OR_READONLY, insufficient access rights on object id: []
```

I've provided screenshots below that might help.
I also added the needed FSL policy picker custom permissions.

[image: Error appears after selecting a recommended schedule]
[image: Console log error]
[image: Permission Sets Assignment]
[image: Permission Set License Assignments]
[image: Custom permissions assigned]

Comment: The ID referenced is from Assigned Resource object, if this helps. I know this post is a bit old.